# Can anyone please tell me what's wrong this socket event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, dom-events

I've emitted two events on user joined & left (`user_joined` and `user_left`). It's working on the server-side but not working on the client-side.

**Server-side code: (it's working, showing console.log on every connection)**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    const id = socket.id;

    /**
     * User Join Function
     */
    socket.on('join', function ({ name, room }) {
        const { user } = addUser({id, name, room}); // add user to users array
        socket.join(user.room);
        socket.emit('user_joined', users); // emit event with modified users array
        console.log(id, 'joined')
    })

    /**
     * User Disconnect function
     */
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        removeUser(id); // remove user form users array
        socket.emit('user_left', users);  // emit event with modified users array
        console.log(id, 'left')
    })


})
```

**Client-side code: (Not firing on `user_joined` or `user_left`)**

```
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';
socket = io(ENDPOINT);

useEffect(() => {
    const name = faker.name.firstName() + ' ' + faker.name.lastName();
    socket.emit('join', {name, room: 'global'}); // it's working fine

    return () => {
        socket.emit('disconnect');
        socket.off();
    }

}, [])

useEffect(() => {

    socket.on('user_joined', (users) => {
        setPlayers(users);
    }); // >>> Not Working <<<

    socket.on('user_left', (users) => {
        setPlayers(users);
    }); // >>> Not Working <<<

    console.log(socket) // it's working fine

}, [players]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `socket` instance needs to be created only once. In your case, it is getting created on every re-render. Also you do not need 2 `useEffects`.

Put the creation of `socket` instance and merge your 2 `useEffects` into 1 and provide an empty array as dependency. With this, your useEffect is executed only once and not on every re-render.

**Try this**

```js
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    const name = faker.name.firstName() + ' ' + faker.name.lastName();
    socket.emit('join', {name, room: 'global'});

    socket.on('user_joined', (users) => {
        setPlayers(users);
    });

    socket.on('user_left', (users) => {
        setPlayers(users);
    });

    console.log(socket);

    return () => {
        socket.emit('disconnect');
        socket.off();
    }

}, []);
...
```

If you want to use the socket instance in other places of your component then make use of `useRef`. With useRef, you always get the same instance unless you mutate it.

**create socket with `refs`**

```js
...
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';

const socketInstance = useRef(io(ENDPOINT));// in react, with useRef, you always get the same instance unless you mutate it.
useEffect(() => {
    // socketInstance.current = io(ENDPOINT);

    const name = faker.name.firstName() + ' ' + faker.name.lastName();
    socketInstance.current.emit('join', {name, room: 'global'});

    socketInstance.current.on('user_joined', (users) => {
        setPlayers(users);
    });

    socketInstance.current.on('user_left', (users) => {
        setPlayers(users);
    });

    console.log(socketInstance.current);

    return () => {
        socketInstance.current.emit('disconnect');
        socketInstance.current.off();
    }

}, []);
...
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? .. and any error you are getting ? see n/w tab and see browser console..

Comment: are you using socket.io ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `socket.io` and `socket.io-client`. No error showing, just not firing the event. Here's the screen record: https://d.pr/free/i/Sh8hvB

Comment: i see - i believe you are using `import io from "socket.io-client";` ..... So, can you initialise your socket like this:  `socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');` ? if it doesn't work, leave a msg and I will take a look at it a bit later on...

Comment: small correction ... try initialising like this --  `const socketInstance = useRef(io.connect('http://localhost:5000'));`

Comment: Still not working, Here's my full code: `component file: ` https://pastebin.com/jP4CYzyD and `server file:` https://pastebin.com/P9nV644y

Comment: Problem solved, Actually event was firing only for current user, `socket.broadcast` solved that. Thanks for your help